# Is there a proverb for "a problem looks so simple when you know the solution"?

Tags: proverbs, proverb-requests

I think I have seen one or two proverbs before that are used in situations where someone thinks a problem/puzzle is very easy but only because he/she has heard the answer to the problem/puzzle.

Is anyone familiar with those proverbs?

Comment: It does ring a bell but ... I can't remember.

Comment: Have you researched the question before asking? This may help: https://grammarist.com/proverb/hindsight-is-20-20-and-20-20-hindsight/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that might help -

## Be wise after the event -

> If you say that someone is *wise after the event*, you mean that they
>   understand a situation and know how to deal with it, but only because
>   it has already happened.
>
> > *I still feel I should have done more to try and stop him getting into
> >     the car, but it's easy to be wise after the event.*

([idioms.thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/it%27s+easy+to+be+wise+after+the+event))

I think this seems to be close to what you are asking, alongside "***20-20 hindsight***" or "***hindsight is 20-20***" mentioned by @OrbitalAussie.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.